# How to close hidden InDesign documents?

Tags: error-handling, adobe-indesign, extendscript

While scripting InDesign, I've had plenty of instances where I create a new document that's hidden until I execute all of the actions, and then I use myDocument.windows.add(); to get it to show. However, I've also had plenty of instances where I get an error before that last step, so the document doesn't materialize. The only way I've been able to get them to close out is to close out InDesign completely; though this works I figure there has to be a better way.

Is there a way, either in the IDE or by a script, to see what's open and/or close all hidden processes?

Cheers,
Brendan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure !

app.documents.everyItem().close(SaveOptions.NO); //will close any document visible or not without saving them ).

It's always a good idea to use a try catch statement in case you want to use invisible documents. So in case of errors, you can discard them.

```
function dealWithInvisibleDocs()
{
    var doc;

    try
    {
        doc = app.documents.add();
        throw new Error ( "Booom" );
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
        if ( doc.isValid )
        {
           doc.close ( SaveOptions.NO );
        }
    }
}
dealWithInvisibleDocs();
```

Loic

Comment: Good stuff; thanks for sharing. I just made a one-line script that I can call on when I need! If I were to do the try/catch, the try part would pretty much have to encompass the entire script, right? And, since I'm still pretty new to error handling, why do the isValid check before closing? I know it's off-topic from the original question but I'd like to know :)

Comment: Yep, using try catch require that you encapsulate the script. Another approach would be to run a loop through documents and see if one has a layoutWindow.
isValid is for checking if the document is existing but I think it would be better to add a instanceof checking:
if ( doc instanceof Document && doc.isValid)…
Loic

Comment: Whoops! Never acknowledged this comment...thanks for your response!